# Call links from the site when using the shortcut API - white page

Tags: php, api, shortcut

i have a Problem with shortcut links site ,
when i use API by this way http://hulklink.net/api.php?key=534287562&url=google.com
Does not show links ... but i sure my code is correct .

i think the Problem is this site don't show short link in same page
but show it in Another path
like this http://hulklink.net/apiget.php

that's my code

```
<?php

function get_vgd($url)
{

$apiurl = "http://hulklink.net/api.php?key=534287562&url=$url";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$apiurl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

echo get_vgd("http://google.com");

?>
```

thnx .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that website is using a redirect to display the shorten link.

Turn on follow redirects for curl.

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);